# Python 3: Multiply a vector by a matrix without NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, vector

I'm fairly new to Python and trying to create a function to multiply a vector by a matrix (of any column size).
e.g.:

```
multiply([1,0,0,1,0,0], [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]])

[1, 1]
```

Here is my code:

```
def multiply(v, G):
    result = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(G)):
        r = G[i]
        for j in range(len(v)):
            total += r[j] * v[j]
        result.append(total)
    return result
```

The problem is that when I try to select the first row of each column in the matrix (r[j]) the error 'list index out of range' is shown. Is there any other way of completing the multiplication without using NumPy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Numpythonic approach: (using `numpy.dot` in order to get the dot product of two matrices)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [3]: np.dot([1,0,0,1,0,0], [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]])
Out[3]: array([1, 1])
```

The Pythonic approach:

The length of your second `for` loop is `len(v)` and you attempt to indexing `v` based on that so you got index Error . As a more pythonic way you can use `zip` function to get the columns of a list then use `starmap` and `mul` within a list comprehension:

```
In [13]: first,second=[1,0,0,1,0,0], [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]]

In [14]: from itertools import starmap

In [15]: from operator import mul

In [16]: [sum(starmap(mul, zip(first, col))) for col in zip(*second)]
Out[16]: [1, 1]
```

Comment: This does not look like it's suitable for a beginner.

Comment: @physicalattraction i will add more description ;)

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't come across the zip function - makes it a lot easier! One last thing, I'm receiving a syntax error when I try to return the sum(mul(k,t)). It's highlighted the outer square brackets, which I assume returns the sum as a list?

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem with your code was that you loop through the rows of the matrix rather than by the columns. Also you don't reset your 'total' variable after each vector*matrix column calculation. This is what you want:

```
def multiply(v, G):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(G[0])): #this loops through columns of the matrix
        total = 0
        for j in range(len(v)): #this loops through vector coordinates & rows of matrix
            total += v[j] * G[j][i]
        result.append(total)
    return result
```

Answer (score 3):

i have attached a code for matrix multiplication do follow the example format for one dimensional multiplication (lists of list)

```
def MM(a,b):
c = []
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    temp=[]
    for j in range(0,len(b[0])):
        s = 0
        for k in range(0,len(a[0])):
            s += a[i][k]*b[k][j]
        temp.append(s)
    c.append(temp)

return c
a=[[1,2]]
b=[[1],[2]]
print(MM(a,b))
```

result is [[5]]

Answer (score 2):

`r` is an element from `G` so it's a row which only has two elements. That means you can't use index `j` to get a value from `r` because `j` goes from 0 till the length of `v`, which is 6 in your example.

Answer (score 2):

I needed solution where the first matrix could be 2-dimensional. Extending the solution from @Kasramvd to accept a two dimensional `first` matrix. Posted here for reference:

```
>>> first,second=[[1,0,0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,1,0,0]], [[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[1,0],[1,1],[0,1]]
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> from operator import mul
>>> [[sum(starmap(mul, zip(row, col))) for col in zip(*second)] for row in first]
[[1, 1], [3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# check matrices
A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
B = [[1,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,6]]

def custom_mm(A,B):    
    if len(A[0]) == len(B): -- condition to check if matrix multiplication is valid or not. Making sure matrix is nXm and mXy
        result = [] -- final matrix
        for i in range(0,len(A)): -- loop through each row of first matrix
            temp = [] -- temporary list to hold output of each row of the output matrix where number of elements will be column of second matrix
            for j in range(0,len(B[0])): -- loop through each column of second matrix
                total = 0 
                l = 0 -- dummy index to switch row of second matrix 
                for k in range(0,len(A[0])):
                    total += A[i][k]*B[l][j]
                    l = l+1
                temp.append(total)
            result.append(temp)                
        return result
    else:
        return (print("not possible"))

print(custom_mm(A,B))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a code that help u to multiply two matrix:

> ```
> A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
> B=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
> matrix=[]
>
> def multiplicationLineColumn(line,column):
>     try:
>         sizeLine=len(line)
>         sizeColumn=len(column)
>         if(sizeLine!=sizeColumn):
>             raise ValueError("Exception")
>         res = sum([line[i] * column[i] for i in range(sizeLine)])
>         return res
>     except ValueError:
>         print("sould have the same len line & column")
>
> def  getColumn(matrix,numColumn):
>     size=len(matrix)
>     column= [matrix[i][numColumn] for i in range(size)]
>     return column
>
> def getLine(matrix,numLine):
>     line = matrix[numLine]
>     return line
>
> for i in range(len(A)):
>     matrix.append([])
>     for j in range(len(B)):
>         matrix[i].append(multiplicationLineColumn(getLine(A,i),getColumn(B,j)))
>
> print(matrix)
> ```

Comment: Could you explain why your answer is better than the others posted.

Comment: @user_3pij is not better than others but this is a native code that dont use numpy
I wanted to show that we can do the same task just by basics python