# Multiplying Boolean Matrices

Tags: python, matrix, boolean

I am trying to explicitly multiple 2 Boolean matrices, regardless of the number of rows or columns.

For example if `A = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]` and `B = [[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]],` then the product is `[[0, 1], [1, 1]]`.

Edit: I want to this explicitly without the `numpy`.

Comment: those arent the same size though

Comment: if you are happy to use `numpy` then `import numpy as np`;`np.dot(A,B)`

Comment: Those aren't booleans, they're integer values.

Comment: booleans can be expressed as numbers, 0 as false, 1 as true

Comment: What did you try? The formula for matrix multiplication is known, and it shouldn't be hard to translate it to python.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45159105/9350699) works without `numpy`:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import mul
A = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
B = [[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]]
result = [[sum(starmap(mul, zip(row, col))) for col in zip(*B)] for row in A]
print(result)
>> [[0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Comment: this seems good, but im not familiar with starmap and zip

Comment: You'd need to import `starmap`, though, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Install numpy (pip install numpy)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[0,1,1],[1,0,1]], dtype=bool)
b = np.matrix([[1,0],[0,0],[0,1]], dtype=bool)
print(a*b)
```

This produces the result:

[[False  True]
[ True  True]]

Which is the same as [[0,1],[1,1]]

Answer (score 0):

You could first tranfer it to ndarray, and then multiply them.

```
import numpy as np


A = np.array( [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]], dtype=bool)
B = np.array([[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]], dtype=bool)
result = np.dot(A, B)

print(result)
```

Comment: If you definitely want to do boolean array multiplication, why not first use number instead and then replace 0 by False and 1 by True. Then you get the result.

Answer (score 0):

I [found an answer](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/multiply-matrix) without any unnecessary imports:

```
>>> A = [[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
>>> B = [[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]]
>>> [[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(X_row,Y_col)) for Y_col in zip(*B)] for X_row in A]
[[0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
>> np.matmul(A,B)

array([[0, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```